# Where can I ask a question about some famous person biography's detail?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is there any specific site, where I could ask a question about some detail in biography of some well known / famous / public person? For example:

- Which university Bill Gates has graduated?
- How old was Donald Trump when he earned his first million?

etc. Is there any site good for such questions to not get them closed as off-topic?